# Java While loop condition isn't being exicuted

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

I'm working on a project for school but I can't figure out why my code isn't exiting when I type "zzz". it's probably simple and I'll likely feel dumb when I know what the problem is. here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringSort2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    String[] arr = new String[15];
    System.out.println("Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit");
    arr[0] = input.nextLine();
    counter++;

     do{     
         arr[counter] = input.nextLine();
         if (input.equals("zzz")){
             System.out.println("bleh");
         }
         counter++;

     } while (!input.equals("zzz") && counter <= 14);

     Arrays.sort(arr);
     System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: `input` is a `Scanner`. It will never equal a `String`.

Comment: You are comparing input, which is the scanner instead of the arr where you stored the input.

Comment: `input` is never "zzz" as it is a Scanner, but "zzz" is a String and those two are incomparable. You probably want to check user's last input, so `arr[counter]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (arr[counter].equals("zzz")) {
    System.out.println("bleh");
}
counter++;
```

with

```
if (arr[counter].equals("zzz")) {
    System.out.println("bleh");
} else {
    counter++;
}
```

and

```
while (!input.equals("zzz") && counter <= 14)
```

with

```
while (!arr[counter].equals("zzz") && counter <= 14)
```

**Explanation:** `zzz` is a string which you have to compare with the input string stored in `arr[counter]`.

Also, in order to avoid `NullPointerException`, you should perform `sort` operation on the copy of the array without any `null` element. Given below is the complete program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringSort2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        String[] arr = new String[15];
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit: ");
            arr[counter] = input.nextLine();
            if (arr[counter].equals("zzz")) {
                System.out.println("bleh");
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        } while (!"zzz".equals(arr[counter]) && counter <= 14);
        arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, counter);
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit: a
Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit: b
Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit: c
Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit: zzz
bleh
Array is [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringSort2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        String[] arr = new String[15];
        System.out.println("Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit");
        arr[counter] = input.nextLine();
        counter++;

         do{     
              arr[counter] = input.nextLine();
             if (arr[counter].equals("zzz")){System.out.println("bleh");}
                counter++;

        }while (!arr[counter].equals("zzz") && counter <= 14);

         Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    } 

}
```

You meant to compare the input String, not the Scanner object. I also removed your magic number "0" index that you had , since you already set your counter to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is that input is the scanner object, and the equals method on the scanner object doesn't refer to the data being read by it. A way of doing this so that it works would be:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Help {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        String[] arr = new String[15];
        String inputString = null;

        System.out.println("Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit");
        do{     
            inputString = input.nextLine();
            arr[counter] = inputString;
            if (inputString.equals("zzz")){System.out.println("bleh");}
            counter++;

        }while (!inputString.equals("zzz") && counter <= 14);

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a `Scanner`. It will never equal a `String`.

Try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;  // this is now a proper string to compare

String[] arr = new String[15];

System.out.println("Enter item or type 'zzz' to quit");
input = sc.nextLine();

int counter = 0;
while (counter < arr.length) {     
   if (input.equals("zzz")) return;  // check most recently entered input
   arr[counter++] = input; // if not returned, store in the list and increase counter
   input = sc.nextLine();  // prompt next line
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```